# Why is my streaming portaudio "cut up and staticy!?"

Tags: c, audio-streaming, portaudio

Just compile my two .c files separately on your system ( https://github.com/Xenland/P2P-Crypt )

```
gcc ./p2pcrypt_tool_udp_receive.c -o p2pcrypt_tool_udp_receive -lportaudio -lpthread `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
```

Run the crypt file and the p2pcrypt_tool_udp_receive file simultaneously and start talking into your microphone and you'll hear the speakers output a semi-whole stream -- the audio is choppy and staticy -- I would like to know how to make the buffer play smooth I'm not sure whats wrong.... Do you know what's wrong with this code?

Comment: You may have better luck submitting something shorter and simpler. There's a whole range of things that could be wrong. In the process of simplifying, you will narrow down the possibilities or find the problem yourself. http://sscce.org/

Comment: How would I have ever gone through life with out your wisdom. seriously, This is an isolated test case of PortAudio + UDP streaming. I have both my write/read ring-buffers indicating that they never overrun or underrun. When printing values in the console the UDP on the receiving end matches the values exactly on the Streaming end. The issue I’m guessing is that the UDP packets are not coming in fast enough to provide the buffer but I don't know how to check for this?When I am recording and playing locally it sounds clear but when I stream through networking I can hear my voice but with static

Comment: To those who are aware of PortAudio example scripts; I should note that the choppiness is apparent in the ./paex_read_write_wire (due to under runs) however there is no static present.

Comment: Use tcpdump (which will dump udp, despite the name) or something similar to see the timing, order and other characteristics of the data stream. 

Static seems strange, since that implies that the data is being corrupted... Try sending a known pattern of audio, and compare it at the other end. Perhaps you are doing some dodgy math somewhere that messes it up?

Comment: Those are some good suggestions, thanks I'll try those out and post back.